# Use VBA to replace sporadic #N/A cells with a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have data that comes from different sources via Get Data/Connections that goes into a sheet/table called RawData. I have created a macro linked to a button the user must click to fill in some of the data in RawData with an index/match function that points to another workbook where the reservation number from RawData is matched to the other workbook to determine the length of stay.

I am not appending said workbook to the RawData table for different reasons. I can go that route if need be but I figured there would be an easier route before we cross that bridge. The issue I have is that once the macro is ran, the other workbook, at times, may not have the reservation data. In these cases, I had to manually determine this data.

This new data can be placed within my main workbook [but I currently have it in it's own workbook (LOSNAintoActualLOS.xlsm) as I've been running tests on making this work]. And the formula has to be pasted into the table because when the table refreshes, the row of data that would normally have the length of stay removes the formula and replaces it with it's original value, a blank cell.

What I need is for my code to loop through all the cells within the F column of a table, determine the cells with #N/A errors, then paste a formula in the error cell. I have done some research and can't seem to find something that suits my needs. I attempted doing this as a loop but seeing as I'm still pretty new to VBA coding, it's definitely not my strong suit.

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim r As Integer
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F" & LastRow)
For r = 2 To LastRow
  If .IsError(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & r)).Value Then
    .Formula = "INDEX(LOSNAintoActualLOS.xlsm!Table1[#Data],MATCH([@Reservation],LOSNAintoActualLOS.xlsm!Table1[Reservation],0),7)"
    .Value = .Value
  End If
Next r
End With
End Sub
```

When I run the code for my If statement I get Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. If I remove the first period from .IsError I get Compile error: Invalid qualifier.

Comment: related: [... finds blanks in a column, and then fills in the value ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211793/need-to-make-a-macro-in-excel-that-finds-blanks-in-a-column-and-then-fills-in-t/43211921#43211921) Change .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) to .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IsError` is not part of `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F" & LastRow)`

Switch it up like this.

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim r As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For r = 2 To LastRow
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & r)
        If IsError(.Value) Then
            .Formula = "INDEX(LOSNAintoActualLOS.xlsm!Table1[#Data],MATCH([@Reservation],LOSNAintoActualLOS.xlsm!Table1[Reservation],0),7)"
            .Value = .Value
        End If
    End With
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: I just tried it on the test sheet and it worked. Glad to know I was pretty close. Thank you so much!

Comment: @A.S.H. Just missed deleting it when I decided to go with the with block